# why is this django template elif not working

Tags: django, django-templates

I can't figure out why this simple if ... else ... endif is not working. The two variables being compared in the if are equal in the page output so the if should not trigger but it does. Any help is appreciated.

```
{% if view.get_player_id != user.id %}

<h1>'{{ view.get_player_id }}' '{{ user.id }}' Only {{ view.get_player_name }} can edit this page</h1>

{% else %}
...
{% endif %}
```

And this is the page output:

```
'4' '4' Only Leo Messi can edit this page
```

Comment: `view.get_player_id` might be a string. Make sure it is passed as an integer, or change `user.id` to a string.

Comment: You could also cast `view.get_player_id` to an integer, just for the comparison: `{% if int(view.get_player_id) != user.id %}`...

Comment: Yes, that was it! view.get_player_id() was returning self.kwargs['pk'] which I am now casting to int.